# Why blend soup in blender if you can use a stick blender?

Tags: soup

if a recipe calls for soup to be put in a blender can I just use a stick blender? Or Is there some difference that makes it better in a regular blender?

Comment: Hi, Menachem! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Can you clarify what you intend to get out of this question? Do you want to understand what are the different types of blender and when should you use them? Or do you want to know if a recipe that calls for a stand blender can be done with a hand blender? Right now your question is both not clear and looking like a rant - which is against the [community guidelines](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Can you edit your question?

Comment: Hi ok to clarify, definitely not a rant; I simply wanted to know if the methods are interchangeable as I do not want to be pouring hot pots of soup into blenders if there is no reason to be was curious why people would do so if that is the case. PS I edited the post

Comment: Another alternative if you do make a lot of soup, is a dedicated soup maker. I have one of these & it's just *sooo easy*! "Which" magazine did a rundown of the types - https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/soup-makers/article/choosing-the-best-soup-maker [the actual 'which is best' section may be paywalled, the overview isn't.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've answered your own question in your comment, really.  One advantage of a stick blender is that you don't have to deal with hot soup in a stand-up blender. The advantage of a high-powered, stand-up blender is that it can puree very well.  However, hot liquids are problematic in these blenders. They expand and can create a mess, and potentially burn you if you are not careful and do not know how to control for this.  I use my stick blender for soups, but also for many small batch needs as well...when I don't want to drag out the blender, or the batch is too small for the jar.  So, in general, they are interchangeable, but in most cases the stand up version will puree more smoothly, and is (obviously) hands-free.

Comment: I don't own a stick blender, so what I usually do for soups is let them cool down a bit, blend on the stand blender and then put them back in the pan (also including the rinsing liquid) for finishing heating and final proofing. Another advantage of the stick blender is that it handles smaller quantities better than a stand blender.